# How can I add additional custom fields to ECS logging winston?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, winston

This is for a Node/JS application. Currently this works:

```
const winston = require('winston')
const ecsFormat = require('@elastic/ecs-winston-format')
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  format: ecsFormat(), 
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console()
  ]
})

logger.info('hi')
logger.error('oops there is a problem', { err: new Error('boom') })
```

The logs output fine to the console but I want to add additional fields such as service name and others. I still want the format and fields currently in ecsFormat but want to add extras.

Comment: ECS logging is "Elastic Common Schema (ECS) logging." Not AWS Elastic Container Service. Are you actually using AWS Elastic Container Service (AWS ECS)? Or is that tag on your question irrelevant to what you are actually doing?

Comment: Sorry about that. It is just ECS logging (not AWS)

Answer (score 0):

You specify extra fields to be added *by default* under the `defaultMeta` property when setting up the logger itself, e.g.

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  format: ecsFormat(/* options */),
  defaultMeta: {
    myCustomField: 'hello',
  },
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
});

logger.info('hi')
```

will yield

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-11-21T14:05:58.747Z","ecs.version":"8.10.0","log.level":"info","message":"hi","myCustomField":"hello"}
```

Further, you can pass custom fields on a per-message level when doing the logging itself, e.g.

```
logger.info('hi', {anotherExtra: 'hello'})
```

will yield

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-11-21T14:05:58.747Z","ecs.version":"8.10.0","log.level":"info","message":"hi","myCustomField":"hello", "anotherExtra": "hello"}
```